# how to create a view on two different tables containing the same columns with different data

Tags: mysql, view

I have two table account (contains the active customer information ) and account_draft (contains the draft information)

Account

```
id  |description       |currency_code| status |
----|------------------|-------------|--------|
1     AccountTransfer       SGD         Active
2     CTS                   SGD         Active


Account-draft
id  |description       |currency_code| status |
----|------------------|-------------|--------|
1     AccountTransfer       SGD         Approved
2       CTS                 SGD         pending
3       payment             SGD         deleted
```

how to create view contains the data of both the tables (active and draft) and identify the each record based on status.
Active tables contains the records with status(active) where as draft table contains the record with status (draft,approved,pending,hold)

View looks like below,

View_account

```
id  |description       |currency_code| status | Type      | 
----|------------------|-------------|--------|-----------|
1     AccountTransfer       SGD         Active     active
1     AccountTransfer       SGD         Approved   draft
2     CTS                   SGD         Active     active
2     CTS                   SGD         pending    draft
3     payment               SGD         deleted    draft
```

pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` query, adding an extra column `Type` based on which table you read data from:

```
CREATE VIEW alldata AS
SELECT id, description, currency_code, status, 'active' AS Type
FROM Account
UNION ALL
SELECT id, description, currency_code, status, 'draft'
FROM `Account-draft`
ORDER BY id, status
```

Then you can

```
SELECT *
FROM alldata
```

Output:

```
id  description         currency_code   status      Type
1   AccountTransfer     SGD             Active      active
1   AccountTransfer     SGD             Approved    draft
2   CTS                 SGD             Active      active
2   CTS                 SGD             pending     draft
3   payment             SGD             deleted     draft
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80c26c/1)